# How to check python version using C++?

Tags: c++, windows

I want to use C ++ to confirm local windows system python version installed, I do not know How to determine?

Comment: What do you want to happen in the event that multiple python versions are installed?

Comment: Thanks for attention, if I can get them all, that will be best.

Answer (score 2):

If the `python` directory has been added to the `PATH` environment variable, you can easily [`_popen`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/96ayss4b.aspx) `python` with the `--version` argument, and parse out the version number from the standard output (which will be e.g. `Python 2.7.6`).

Another option would be to use `regedit` to see if the version appears somewhere in the registry that you can read it from.  Lots of existing S.O. Q&A on how to read registry values....

If you get stuck implementing either option, post your code and the specific problem.